# How to build openssl-devel package from sources?

Tags: compilation, openssl, centos

I need to install openssl-devel package on CentOS 6 for nginx+openssl-1.1.1 compilation. But for CentOS 6 is only available 1.0.2 version. It's not a problem to compile openssl-1.1.1 from sources, but i can't find any information about openssl-devel.

How to compile this package? I can't find openssl-devel sources or maybe i can compile this package from usual openssl sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I hope it is obvious that you can not / should not be reusing the same package names when attempting to build packages for a newer major OpenSSL version than the one used across CentOS 6. If you *do* that you will likely break the operating system because anything that relies on OpenSSL will likely fail due to missing/deprecated functions in the newer library compared to OpenSSL 1.0.x which the CentOS 6 programs are linked/compiled with.

What you should be doing is similar to what EPEL did for CentOS 7: create a package `openssl11` (and subsequently, e.g. `openssl11-devel`, etc.) which ships the newer library under a different name.

Then any app that is meant to be rebuilt with newer OpenSSL in mind, should "link" (aka `BuildRequires:` against `openssl11-devel`.

So what you're after is:

- fetch `.src.rpm` for `openssl11` of EL7, e.g. [here](https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/Packages/o/openssl11-1.1.1c-2.el7.src.rpm)
- rebuild it for EL6: as a bare minimum you would need to disable some patches which assume newer glibc and fix an issue related to [stripping binaries](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/build-rpms-gotchas#relocation-type-42)
- build any packages you want to compile against OpenSSL 1.1.1 with `BuildRequires: openssl11-devel` package

Comment: Thank you for recommending my `openssl11` package rather some bad hackery! :)